# Parsing a CSV with irregular quoting rules using readr

Tags: r, regex, tidyverse, readr

I have a weird CSV that I can't parse with readr. Let's call it `data.csv`. It looks something like this:

```
name,info,amount_spent
John Doe,Is a good guy,5412030
Jane Doe,"Jan Doe" is cool,3159
Senator Sally Doe,"Sally "Sal" Doe is from New York, NY",4451
```

If all of the rows were like first one below the columns row – two character columns followed by an integer column – this would be easy to parse with `read_csv`:

```
df <- read_csv("data.csv")
```

However, some rows are formatted like the second one, in that the second column ("info") contains a string, part of which is enclosed by double quotes and part of which is not. This makes it so read_csv doesn't read the comma after the word `cool` as a delimiter, and the entire following row gets appended to the offending cell.

A solution for this kind of problem is to pass `FALSE` to the `escape_double` argument in `read_delim()`, like so:

```
df <- read_delim("data.csv", delim = ",", escape_double = FALSE)
```

This works for the second row, but gets killed by the third, where the second column contains a string enclosed by double quotes which itself contains nested double quotes *and* a comma.

I have read the readr documentation but have as yet found no solution that would parse both types of rows.

Comment: Where did this csv come from? That's basically an invalid CSV. I would try to fix the process that generated the data rather than try to hack the import routine to work around it.

Comment: `data.table::fread()` reads the sample data correctly.

Comment: With the warning `Found and resolved improper quoting in first 100 rows`

Comment: @MrFlick It's Facebook's weekly ads spending data. If you download the first one and try to parse the "SpendingToDate" file, you'll see what I mean. https://www.facebook.com/ads/archive/report/?source=archive-landing-page

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me with the example specified.

Used read.csv rather than read_csv.
This means I am using a dataframe rather than a tibble.

```
#Read the csv, just turned the table you had as an example to a csv.
#That resulted as a csv with one column
a <- read.csv(file = "Book1.csv", header=T) 

#Replace the comma in the third(!) line with just space
a[,1] <-  str_replace_all(as.vector(a[,1]), ", ", " ")

#Use seperate from the tidyer package to split the column to three columns
#and convert to a tibble
a <- a %>% separate(name.info.amount_spent, c("name", "info", "spent"), ",")%>%
as_tibble(a)
glimpse(a)
 $name  <chr> "John Doe", "Jane Doe", "Senator Sally Doe"
 $info  <chr> "Is a good guy", "\"Jan Doe\" is cool", "\"Sally \"Sal\" Doe is from New York NY\""
 $spent <chr> "5412030", "3159", "4451"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression which splits on the comma in question (using `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)`):

```
input <- c('John Doe,Is a good guy,5412030', 'Jane Doe,"Jan Doe" is cool,3159',
           'Senator Sally Doe,"Sally "Sal" Doe is from New York, NY",4451')

lst <- strsplit(input, '"[^"]*"(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|,', perl = T)

(df <- setNames(as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, lst)), c("name","info","amount_spent")))
```

This yields

```
               name                                   info amount_spent
1          John Doe                          Is a good guy      5412030
2          Jane Doe                      "Jan Doe" is cool         3159
3 Senator Sally Doe "Sally "Sal" Doe is from New York, NY"         4451
```

See a demo for the expression on [**regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/lIVfTC/1).